# Bootstrap 3 tap on list-group-item lags before toggling active class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, mobile-devices

On some mobile devices, why does a tap on a list-group-item lag before it adds the `active` class to it?

We are using Bootstrap 3 and created a simple list-group with three items. On click, the `active` class is toggled on the item. This works normally on desktop browsers, but when I test my site on a mobile device (used Samsung Galaxy S3 stock browser and an iPad Mini with Safari), the tap on the list-group-item works, but it takes a full second or so for the `active` class to be toggled. This feels weird, since when you tap a button, you expect it to immediately change status.

There is around a 500ms delay onclick on an iPad Mini with Safari: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OrYu1SOQzjY

It's around 1 second delay on a Galaxy S3 with stock browser.

At first I thought this lag might be due to other actions being performed in our code when tapping on a list-group-item, but I created a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/hZ2uF2KS7O) with nothing else but the list-group, and I experienced the same lag, even with nothing else going on but the toggling of the `active` class.

http://www.bootply.com/hZ2uF2KS7O

I wondered if this was due to some CSS `transition` property or something, but when inspecting the list-group-item in Dev Tools, I don't see any `transition` property.

Is there a way to eliminate the lag? What is causing it?

Comment: Seems pretty lag free on my device (HTC One/Android)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OrYu1SOQzjY This is on an iPad Mini. You can see the lag is better but still around 500ms or so. It's around 1 second lag on my Galaxy S3 (stock browser).

Comment: Looks less than 500ms, but is a little slow. I personally don't have any other device here to test with, perhaps when I get home I can dig out an old Android tablet and an iPad 2. But the HTC is instantaneous using Chrome. Have you tried not using stock browser on the S3?

Comment: Hmm, very strange. I tested on a friend's Nexus 7 v1 with Chrome and Firefox, and the delay was almost unnoticeable. I also tested on a friend's Samsung Galaxy Nexus (original) with Chrome, and the delay was also almost unnoticeable. How on earth could jQuery's `toggleClass` function be slowing down certain browsers? That's all that should be happening!

Comment: The Android stock browser tends to be pretty crappy; extra slowness wouldn't be surprising.

Comment: @cvrebert, what about Safari on an iPad Mini? I wouldn't have expected that to be slow as well. And I still don't get how a simple `toggleClass` on one element could cause lag. Any thoughts?